# Parsing html in Python 2.7 with regex - don't really understand that

Tags: html, regex, string, parsing, python-2.7

Sorry for being kinda dumb, but I really need help in Python.

```
['<a href="needs to be cut out">Foo to BAR</a>', '<a href="this also needs to be cut out">BAR to Foo</a>']
```

So I have this tuple, and I need to cut out what's inside that href attribute and what's inside `<a>` tag - basically, I want to get a tuple that looks like:

```
[["needs to be cut out", "Foo to BAR"], ["this also needs to be cut out", "BAR to Foo"]]
```

inside href attribute there are a lot of special symbols for example,

```
<a href="?a=p.stops&amp;direction_id=23600&amp;interval=1&amp;t=wml&amp;l=en">
```

As I think, there's too much trouble in using HTML parsers if I really don't need to try to parse the object tree but only need a few url's and words from the webpage. But I can't really understand how to form regexes. Regexes that I formed seem to be completely wrong. So I'm asking if somebody could help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a HTML parser anyway. Python comes with a few included, and the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is easier to get working than a regular expression for even simple `<a>` tags with arbitrary attributes:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

texts = []
for linktext in linkslist:
    link = ET.fromstring(linktext)
    texts.append([link.attrib['href'], link.text])
```

If you use `' '.join(link.itertext())` you can get the text out of *anything* nested under the `<a>` tag, if you find that some of the links have nested `<span>`, `<b>`, `<i>` or other inline tags to mark up the link text further:

```
for linktext in linkslist:
    link = ET.fromstring(linktext)
    texts.append([link.attrib['href'], ' '.join(link.itertext())])
```

This gives:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> linkslist = ['<a href="needs to be cut out">Foo to BAR</a>', '<a href="this also needs to be cut out">BAR to Foo</a>']     
>>> texts = []
>>> for linktext in linkslist:
...     link = ET.fromstring(linktext)
...     texts.append([link.attrib['href'], ' '.join(link.itertext())])
... 
>>> texts
[['needs to be cut out', 'Foo to BAR'], ['this also needs to be cut out', 'BAR to Foo']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup for parsing the HTML entities.

According to your problem you already have following list:

```
l = ['<a href="needs to be cut out">Foo to BAR</a>', '<a href="this also needs to be cut out">BAR to Foo</a>']
```

Now all you need is following code.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

parsed_list = []

for each in l:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(each)
    parsed_list.append([soup.find('a')['href'], soup.find('a').contents[0]])
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Easy Html Parser EHP for that.

check out https://github.com/iogf/ehp

```
lst = ['<a href="needs to be cut out">Foo to BAR</a>', '<a href="this also needs to be cut out">BAR to Foo</a>', '<a href="?a=p.stops&amp;direction_id=23600&amp;interval=1&amp;t=wml&amp;l=en">']

data = [(tag.text(), attr.get('href'))for indi in lst
            for tag, name, attr in Html().feed(indi).walk() if attr.get('href')]


data
```

Output:

```
[('Foo to BAR', 'needs to be cut out'), ('BAR to Foo', 'this also needs to be cut out'), ('', u'?a=p.stops&direction_id=23600&interval=1&t=wml&l=en')]
```